# rdd.saveAsTextFile doesn't seem to work, but repetitions throw FileAlreadyExistsException

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I'm running `dataFrame.rdd.saveAsTextFile("/home/hadoop/test")` in an attempt to write a data frame to disk. This executes with no errors, but the folder is not created. Furthermore, when I run the same command again (in the shell) an Exception is thrown:

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx.ec2.internal:8020/home/hadoop/feet already exists
```

Any idea why this is? Is there a nuance of the submission move (client, cluster) that affects this?

EDIT:

I have permission to create directories in `/home/hadoop` but I cannot create directories inside any of the dirs/sub-dirs created by `rdd.saveAsTextFile("file:/home/hadoop/test")`. The structure looks like this:

`/home/hadoop/test/_temporary/0`

How are `_temporary` and `0` being created if I do not have permission to create directories inside `test` from the command line? Is there a way to change the permission of these created directories?

Edit2:

In the end I wrote to s3 instead using `rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("s3://...")`. This is only viable if you have a very small output - because `coalesce(n)` will cause the RDD to exist and be processed further on only n workers. In my case, I chose 1 worker so that the file would be generated by one worker. This gave me a folder containing one `part-00000` file which had all of my data.

Comment: It could be a silly question but where do you look for an output? It looks like you intended to use a local file system but file is written to HDFS...

Comment: You'll need to remove the existing data before writing unless you want to append the data you want to save to the existing file

Comment: @zero323 I was expecting to find a folder full of part-0000x style files on the master box, which I then plan to merge into one. How can I specify that I want the files written to the local file system - or is there another way to achieve my goal of a single file output?

Comment: You should be able to save to the local path using `rdd.saveAsTextFile("file:///...")` or copy from HDFS using `moveToLocal`. Single file output requires a single partition before save.

Comment: I have used the following command in the SparkConf and it works perfectly well yourSparkConf.set("spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs", "false")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since https://spark-project.atlassian.net/browse/SPARK-1100 saveAsTextFile should never be able to silently overwrite an already existing folder.

If you receive an `java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:...` it probably means you have permission problems when trying to write in the output path.

If you give more context info the answers could be more helpful.
Like: are you running on local shell? cluster shell? which type of cluster?

EDIT: I think you are facing that error because all executors are trying to write to same same path which isn't available on all executors.

Comment: The error occurs when I save to a totally new and unused directory name.

It is definitely a permission issue - I do not have permission to create directories in the subfolders of the folder specified in `saveAsTextFile("file:///path/to/dir")` - see my edit in the OP above.

I'm running on an AWS EMR cluster, in the Spark-Shell.

Comment: Why are you saving locally if you are running on a EMR cluster? Just curious.

Comment: I want to see and/or e-mail the results of the job (it's only about 5 rows), and then automate the whole process.

Comment: Then saving the results of your job inside a the local filesystem of executors doesn't seem a good idea to me.
It's not pertinent with your question but you should probably save it somewhere else (like s3).
Anyway, have you tried to manually ssh into an executor and create the folder you want to create with Spark manually?

Comment: @GPrivi Manually creating the directory in the executor will not work as `saveAsTextFile` will not write in an existing directory. It will see this as overwriting in the directory

Comment: @RoryByrne it might be possible to `collect()` the results and email it from spark job itself without having to save to local disk.

Comment: @shanmuga Yeah that might be the way to go.
@GPrivi does `saveAsTextFile()` save each individual part to the local machine which generates it? Is there a way to get all of the `part-0000x` files on to the master? That's what I thought the functionality was.

Comment: @RoryByrne I think you are facing that error because all executors are trying to write to same same path which isn't available on all executors. 
If you write on s3, the same path will be available to all executors.

Comment: @shanmuga I suggested that only to check if he had permissions to create them

Comment: @GPrivi Is there a way to merge the `part-0000x` files into one on S3? Can Hadoop's FuleUtil do this?

Comment: The simple way is to do a repartition(1) before outputting, you will have a single part-00001 file then.
The hard way is to use saveAsHadoop instead of saveAsTextFile which is a little more "powerful".

Comment: @GPrivi In the end I did a `coalesce(1)` before saving - is that very different to `repartition(1)`?

Comment: @RoryByrne it's actually better, because you avoid a shuffle (don't know if it changes much because we are going to have only 1 partition but still..)

Answer (score 1):

`saveAsTextFile` works. It writes to the default file system (configured by `fs.default.name` in your `core-site.xml`). In this case the default file system is `hdfs://ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx.ec2.internal:8020/`.

If you want to write to local disk, use `saveAsTextFile("file:/home/hadoop/test")`. If you have more than one node in the Spark cluster, the results will be mostly unusable: each node will write some parts of the RDD to local disk. But for testing this may be okay.

Comment: `saveAsTextFile("file:/home/hadoop/test")` does create the folder, but there's no files in any of its subfolders. There are also Exceptions that look like:

`java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/home/hadoop/what/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201508261124_0000_m_000000_6 (exists=false, cwd=file:/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1440587008767_0002/container_1440587008767_0002_01_000003)`